# Java HTTP Request on VPN only website

Tags: java, apache, http, vpn, http-get

I am trying to build a website parser for one of our internal websites (accessible only from the company network - we get on the network through Cisco AnyConnect VPN).

I can access the site fine in any browser, but not using HTTP requests. Windows network and sharing center shows that I have two active networks:

1. The actual internet connection
2. The company network (without internet access).

Default HTTP client gets time out as I suppose it makes a request using the actual internet connection (and the website is not accessible to public), but using this code:

```
HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName("10.x.x.x"));
```

I get the following error:

> I/O exception caught when connectiong to /10.x.x.x -> {s} -> https://zzz.com:443: Network is unreachable: connect

Also, might be a stupid test but I have done a HTTP request to a "what is my ip" site and the IP is shown as my Wifi IP not the IP through VPN (which I get when I open browser and browse to a "what is my ip" website). Same thing (wrong IP) when I try this using a gui-less browser (Jaunt or HTMLUnit).

Please advise if any fixes for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ConnRoutePNames](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/params/ConnRoutePNames.html) appears to be deprecated. See if the following works (I haven't tested):

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("10.x.x.x", 80);
HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, there's definitely some progress. But now for any httpget request to a https website I get a 400 response (200 for http websites).

Comment: This may be of use to you: [Making HTTPS call using Apache HttpClient](http://prasans.info/2014/06/making-https-call-using-apache-httpclient/).

Comment: I have found another workaround(for the 400 code), but your comment solved the actual issue. Thanks

Comment: @breekMD No problem. Out of curiosity, what was the workaround? It might be useful to mention in case others have the same issue.

Comment: i used the http url of the website. using a browser the http connection does not work, only https works. but the java GET request worked on http fine.